# What is the blue color dotted line in microsoft office word?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

When I open MS word 2010, new document, insert cover page and select "annual" template, then there is a blue color small dotted line? What is the name of this line? How can I use it in my own body paragraph to separate it?

Comment: Probably a paragraph border? (Just like table borders but applied to paragraphs)

Comment: Thanks Alvin, It is table border, I think without any border, it looks like that. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Tahmina, what you are describing is most probably the table gridlines which displays where the outline of a table are when there is no border. You can toggle these on and off by clicking on the table and then changing Borders -> View Gridlines.